# Batch file to copy all .zip files from one path to a different path comparing parent folder names

Tags: batch, batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch script to do the following:

I have many folders inside path "C:\FTP"
For example "Folder1" "Folder2". Each folder may have a .zip file or may not.
I'm looking to find a way to copy these .zip files to destination "D:\FTP" that also includes same folder names "Folder1", "Folder2". If the destination doesn't have a folder with the same name then it should create the missing folder and copy the .zip files from source as well.

Anyone has any idea how can i do that?
Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: From what I'm getting, Windows explorer's Copy-Paste will do it for you

Comment: No it won't because the folders also include more files inside except .zip file and it will copy them as well

Comment: Oh, Okay. Got it now

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `robocopy` (standard with windows) using the `/MIR` option (mirror; copies all subdirectories, and PURGES files in the destination that are not in the source).

It supports wildcards so `*.zip` would work.

So `robocopy c:\source d:\destination *.zip /MIR /v /l` would probably work.

- `/v` is verbose logging
- `/l` is list only for testing

There are flags to exclude files and empty directories.

[Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy)

Comment: The problem with this is that it's not possible to have the exact path of source and destination because folders are hundreds. It has to find itself the same folder name of the parent folder to the destination and move the .zip files inside.

Comment: did you try it? Robocopy is designed to do this. You give it the main parent folder of the source and destination. in your example this would be c:\ftp and d:\ftp, and then robocopy will dive all the way down looking for zip files reconstruct the folder tree in the destination to match the source.

Comment: I tried this. Folders except .zip file may also contain other folders inside. It also copies these folders as empty. Same problem as the answer below.

Comment: check the documentation to tailor it. instead of `/mir` try `/s /purge`

Comment: You're awesome! It needs /s for not copying the empty folders and it also needs /xx for not deleting the older files in the destination folders. The final line that works perfectly for me is: `robocopy C:\source D:\destination *.zip /MIR /v /s /XX`
Thank you so much Yorik for your help, i really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Total Commander using filter for *.zip files while copying.

Comment: Folders except .zip file may also contain other folders inside. If i try to copy only .zip files with Total Commander, it also copies the other folders as empty.

Comment: @Sakis then you can remove empty folders also using TC. It has option to search for empty folders. https://www.ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?t=39640

Comment: Too many moves to do something that i need to use daily as fast as possible. That's why my idea was just a simple click on a batch file.

Comment: @Sakis you cannot make it less than writing folder names in the script/bat file. Eventually give them on the command line to the script.